# How to test initializer number of arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, testing, rspec

I need to autograde a Ruby exercise , testing with Rspec

The class is pure ruby and I only have to validate attributes (existence and accessibility) and the number of arguments that are received in the initializer

```rb
# lib/card.rb
class Card
  attr_reader :number, :suit

  def initialize(number, suit)
    @number = number
    @suit = suit
  end
end

# spec/card_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"
require_relative "../lib/card"

describe Card do
  let(:subject) do
    Card.new(1, "D")
  end

  it { expect(Card).to respond_to(:new).with(4).arguments }
end
```

```sh
➜ rspec spec/card_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.00431 seconds (files took 0.12135 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failure
```

Tests are passing despite the fact that the initializer receives 2 arguments and I specify 4 arguments in my test

Comment: For some reason it looks like `respond_to` doesn't work properly with the `new` method. It works for other custom methods though. Might be a bug.

Comment: `it { expect(Card).to respond_to(:new).with(2).arguments }` tests the `self.new` method inside `Card`, which is clearly not what's needed. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Card.new` is defined in `Card.initialize`.

So:

```
it { expect(Card).to respond_to(:new).with(2).arguments }
```

is actually trying to test:

```
class Card
  def self.new(number, suit)
    ...
  end
end
```

You could simply try to initialize `Card` with incorrect arguments and check that `ArgumentError` is raised:

```
class Card
  attr_reader :number, :suit

  def initialize(number, suit)
    @number = number
    @suit = suit
  end
end

describe Card do
  context 'when initialized with incorrect number of arguments' do
    [[], [1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]].each do |args|
      it { expect { Card.new(*args) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError) }
    end
  end

  context 'when initialized with correct arguments' do
    it { expect(Card.new(1, 'D')).to be_a(Card) }
  end
end
```

It outputs:

```
Card
  when initialized with incorrect number of arguments
    should raise ArgumentError
    should raise ArgumentError
    should raise ArgumentError
    should raise ArgumentError
  when initialized with correct arguments
    should be a kind of Card

Finished in 0.01455 seconds (files took 0.64291 seconds to load)
5 examples, 0 failures
```

There might be a cleaner way, though.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` method has an arity of `-1` which means variable number of arguments so it is okay that the spec passes.

See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Method.html#method-i-arity

The problem is that you are testing the wrong thing/method.

Comment: You're correct that `Card.method(:new).arity` is `-1`, just like `Card.method(:initialize).arity`. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Because both `Class#new` and `Object#initialize` cannot know in advance how many arguments the user is going to pass. Note that traditionally, `initialize` is overridden in subclasses for the correct number of parameters, so this is not a problem. E.g. if you examine the `initialize` method defined by the OP instead of the default one in `Object`, it will obviously have an arity of 2.

Comment: @JörgWMittag weird. `Card.method(:initialize).arity` returns -1. Did I miss something?

Comment: @EricDuminil: I don't understand your question. That is `Object#initialize` you are looking at, which is generally meant to be overridden in subclasses, so it is defined to have the maximally flexible signature. In other words, the result is exactly what you would expect, no?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Okay, I think I got it. `Card.instance_method(:initialize).arity` is indeed `2`. The confusion came from the fact that the definition of `Card.new` is in `Card#initialize`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: The definition of `Card.new` is in `Class#new`, not `Card#initialize`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks for your patience. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328096/6419007 cleared my confusion.